# Can I share common code between JavaFX and oracle MAF?

Tags: mobile, javafx, oracle-maf

I wonder if it would be possible using a MVC strategy, encode parts of Model and Control in Java and have two possibilities to code View, one in [JavaFX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-overview.htm#JFXST784) and the other in [Oracle MAF](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/maf/overview/index.html).

I would use JavaFX to develop the desktop version and MAF for the mobile version. I know I could use a port for mobile with [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/labs/javafxports/) but considering that [RoboVM was discontinued](https://robovm.com/) I would not want to bet on this strategy.

I own experience in Java but not used JavaFX or MAF, I doubt if I can do what I want because I found nothing on the internet talking about using the two technologies together to design a multi platform mobile / desktop.
The biggest question is:

> - Is it possible to completely decouple the view from the control and  model or JavaFX and/or MAF, in some circumstance, use a strategy of Control/Vie "tied"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an Oracle Mobile Application Framework (MAF) perspective, as an Oracle product manager for our mobile portfolio I'll make the comment we've not tested JavaFX integration with MAF at all, and as they are completely different UI technologies and have different lifecycles, I doubt this would work at all.  Or it would be an uphill battle all the way & you'd waste a lot of time & hair.  As such I recommend you don't pursue this option.